# Correctly assign HTTPS only custom domain to flex env

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

What is the correct way to map a custom domain to Google App Engine project?

I've added the custom domain, set up all the DNS records etc. and it is working! But how do I enforce HTTPS only? (Like the custom domain generated does)

From reading around *many* posts I have seen `secure: always` in a `handler` which I have tried, but doesn't seem to work (saw some comments that it doesn't work on flex environments?)

So how can I correctly map my domain to a flex php environment being HTTPS only?! Seems such a simple thing to want to be able to do!

Answer (score 1):

While being somewhat related to a custom domain (for example the SSL certificate used by HTTPS being tied to the domain) the HTTPS-only behaviour is not really an attribute of the custom domain mapping operation, it's just a behaviour of the app itself (regardless of being mapped to a custom domain or not).

For standard environment GAE apps part of the HTTPS-only behaviour is an automatic `http` -> `https` redirection performed by the GAE infra on behalf of the app if `secure: always` is set in the `app.yaml` configuration file.

But that configuration has, indeed, been deprecated for the flexible environment GAE apps. The PHP-specific deprecation note can be found at [**app.yaml** changes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/upgrading#appyaml_changes):

> - Secure handlers
>
> The `secure` setting under `handlers` is now deprecated for the App
>   Engine flexible environment. If you need SSL redirection, you can
>   update your application code and use the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header to
>   redirect `http` traffic. You can also use the [HTTP Strict Transport
>   Security response header](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet).

You'll also note that there is no mentioning of `secure` (or `handlers` for that matter) in the [app.yaml Configuration File](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/reference/app-yaml) doc.

So you need to take care of the `http` -> `https` redirection inside your app code (or the framework you use for it, if any and if it has such capability), possibly following the suggestions from the above quote. I can't really help with details on this as I'm not a PHP user.