# Only receiving HTTP requests in Google App Engine Flex with .NET. How to only allow HTTPS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-app-engine

I have a website written in C# using ASP.NET Core MVC5 that I'm deploying onto Google Cloud App Engine Flex. I want to completely disable HTTP and only allow HTTPS. I do not want a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. How do I go about doing this?

I tried searching and could not find any way to specify it in the `app.yaml` for .NET and App Engine Flex. So I tried to do it within the webserver code itself. At first as a test, I tried to use the RequireHttps attribute and I also tried an implementation of RequireHttpsOrClose (https://www.recaffeinate.co/post/enforce-https-aspnetcore-api/), which is closer to what I actually want.

When I built the projects and deploy via IIS (i.e. NOT google app engine), everything works fine. However, when I deploy to Google App Engine, they don't work right. When I try to connect to them, it always seems to come in as HTTP, even if the URL I use to connect is set as HTTPS. When I used the RequireHttps attribute, I got a "too many redirects" error, which tells me that it was taking my HTTPS request (e.g. "https://www.test.com") but within the controller, it was seeing it as if I had sent a plain HTTP request (e.g. like it was seeing "http://www.test.com" instead). So it again saw this as a supposed plain HTTP request (though it really wasn't) and attempted to redirect -- once again -- to an HTTPS request, which was again processed as a plain HTTP request. And this seems to continue infinitely, causing a redirect loop.

To test this further, I checked the value of `Request.IsHttps`, I ALWAYS got `false` even though I was definitely connecting with HTTPS. So for some reason the site is only receiving HTTP requests even though I'm requesting with HTTPS.

Again, when I test outside of App Engine (by deploying as via IIS on our non-Google web server), everything works perfectly. It is only when I deploy on App Engine that I get this weird behavior.

I can reproduce this by setting up a barebones project with "ASP.NET Core on Google Cloud Platform" template. The only relevant code is my controller, which is barebones and simply returns the dummy values supplied by the template:

```
[RequireHttps]
[Route("/")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public ValuesController(ILogger<ValuesController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        // When I remove the RequestHttps attribute in order to stop the redirect 
        // loop, I always get values "not https" and "HTTP/1.1" even though
        // my browser is connecting to https://xxxxx.appspot.com

        if (Request.IsHttps) return new string[] { "https", Request.Protocol };
        return new string[] { "not https", Request.Protocol }; 
    }
}
```

I publish this with an `app.yaml` of:

```
service: testservice
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex
```

The web.config is unmodified from the project template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So my questions are:

1. Why am I only receiving HTTP requests when I am definitely entering a HTTPS URL? Did I do something or set something in Google Cloud or in App Engine to cause this to happen?
2. Otherwise, is there some other method of disabling HTTP and only allowing HTTPS using App Engine Flex with .NET? All examples I could find of disabling it are for Python using `handler` in the `app.yaml`, but that doesn't seem to apply to .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the flexible environment you cannot use the `app.yaml` configuration to require HTTPS-only access, that can only be done in the standard environment. See related [Correctly assign HTTPS only custom domain to flex env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50654961/correctly-assign-https-only-custom-domain-to-flex-env/50661513#50661513)

From [Request limits](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/how-requests-are-handled#request_limits):

> - SSL connections are terminated at the load balancer. Traffic from the load balancer is sent to the instance over an encrypted channel,
>     and then forwarded to the application server over HTTP. The
>     X-Forwarded-Proto header lets you understand if the origin request was
>     HTTP or HTTPs.

This explains why you cannot use `Request.IsHttps` to identify if the request was HTTPS.

But you can modify that piece of logic to check the `X-Forwarded-Proto` instead which *should* get you what you need. I *think* it could be something along these lines (not 100% certain, I'm not a .NET user):

```
    if (Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"] == "https") return new string[] { "https", Request.Protocol };
    return new string[] { "not https", Request.Protocol };
```